# There are no Views in the 2sic App-Media Directory application sample

Tags: 2sxc, dnn9

I've downloaded App-Media Directory 1.0.0.7 from https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/media-directory-app-for-dnn-dotnetnuke, and install it fine, but when I go into Apps Management I do NOT see any Views (or Queries or WebAPIs), and I believe I've seen references to List View and Press Release View.  I also don't find this on GitHub to see if they might be there somehow.

Any ideas? I've not looked at older releases yet.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a quick response to this on the same git-hub question. basically it's a very old ZIP format with an old XML inside it.

Importing it into a 2sxc 8 and re-exporting it fixes stuff, but since the app is very old and uses AngularJS, I don't recommend it.